# Как сделать рассылку через текстовый документ в telebot

Tags: python, telegram, telebot, рассылка

Прошу помощи.
Начала заниматься разработкой телеграмм ботов недавно и в базах данных не шарю. Хочу сделать рассылку в боте по всем пользователям(рассылка с возможностью отправки картинок) но через txt файл, куда будут записываться id пользователей бота при старте. Я пыталась сама, не получилось, спасибо )

Comment: покажите код вашей попытки и опишите где именно у вас возникают трудности

Answer (score 2):

```
# запись id  txt файл, каждый с новой строки
@bot.message_handler(commands=['asd'])
def asd(message):
    f = open('usr.txt', 'a')
    f.write(str(message.chat.id) + '\n')
    f.close()


# отправка сообщения test всем id из файла
@bot.message_handler(commands=['qwe'])
def qwe(message):
    f = open('usr.txt', 'r')
    data = f.readlines()
    for i in data:
        bot.send_message(i, 'test')
    f.close()
```

Comment: А как сделать так, чтобы бот не отправлял сообщение, а пересылал последний пост из канала в котором он администратор

Comment: https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/issues/408